# New to Android: App Crashes When Running While Loop (Threading?)

Tags: java, android, while-loop, append, runnable

I am trying to write and application which, when a button is pressed, will display all the prime numbers from 23 to 499. Now, I know I have my algorithm correct, so that is not the issue as I can run it using S.o.pln in some other Java Development program. The issue I believe lies in my use of a thread as I've never used one before, or maybe my use of a runnable. I could also be where I am appending an integer to a TextView, but, as I am new, I have no idea. Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need anymore context I will be happy to provide it. Thanks...

```
public class PrimeNumbers extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button whatPrime, howManyPrime, resetPrime;
TextView numPrime, ctPrime;
int prime = 23, factor, ct = 0;;
StringBuilder strBuPrime;
String strPrime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.primenumbers);
    initialize();
    whatPrime.setOnClickListener(this);
    howManyPrime.setOnClickListener(this);
    resetPrime.setOnClickListener(this);
}// end onCreate

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    whatPrime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrime);
    howManyPrime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrimeCount);
    resetPrime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrimeReset);
    numPrime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrimeNumbers);
    ctPrime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrimeNumbersCount);
}// end initialize

Runnable findPrimes = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (prime <= 499 && prime >= 23) {
            factor = 3;
            while (prime % factor != 0) // if true start testing
                                        // other
                                        // factors
            {
                while (factor <= (Math.sqrt(prime))) // testing
                                                        // other
                                                        // factors
                {
                    if (prime % factor == 0) // factor found, leave
                                                // while
                    {
                        factor = 2000;
                    }
                    factor++;
                }
                if (factor != 2001) // no factor found but left
                                    // while, print
                                    // prime, add 1 to counter
                {
                    strPrime = Integer.toString(prime);
                    strBuPrime.append(strPrime + '\n');
                }
                factor = 1; // leave while as 1 is a factor of
                            // everything
            }
            prime += 2; // test next prime
        }
        numPrime.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                numPrime.setText(strBuPrime);
            }
        });
    }
};
Thread threadPrimes = new Thread(findPrimes);

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.bPrime:
        threadPrimes.start();
        break;
    case R.id.bPrimeCount:
        ctPrime.setText("There are " + ct
                + " prime numbers from 23 to 499.");
        break;
    case R.id.bPrimeReset:
        numPrime.setText("");
        ctPrime.setText("");
        break;
    }
}// end onClick
```

}

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: Favoring commenting over formatting is not a great idea. You can always stack a group of comments above a loop explaining it's purpose or function but having them offset and allowing them to push your brackets down isn't doing your code any favors.

Comment: "`S.o.pln`", did you really need to abbreviate that? It took me like 5 seconds to figure out what you were talking about...

Comment: How to I get the logcat onto here and what is that?

Answer (score 0):

logcat would help, but you are probably overdoing it with the `post(Runnable)` to append the values to your `TextView`. Try using a `StringBuilder` to concatenate everything and set the text all at once. (Or at least in larger chunks.)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I think your tread is still running in the UI threadpool and causes the UI to lockup.

Android will kill your thread if you lock the UI for ~2-3 seconds. 
AsyncTask will also allow you to display a status bar or spinning ring while the runnable does the work.